# Jupyter-Scala notebook keeps restarting with a NullPointerException

Tags: macos, scala, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to learn Scala with the Jupyter Notebook. I've installed Scala using Homebrew.

```
brew install scala
```

Scala seems to work fine in command line. After executing `jupyter-scala` as per the instructions given in [this site](https://github.com/jupyter-scala/jupyter-scala), I started the Jupyter Notebook with the Scala kernel. The following error pops up.

```
[I 12:35:05.028 NotebookApp] Kernel started: d440cf06-8a67-468c-9da4-ec8a701e0bcf
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jupyter.kernel.server.ServerApp$.apply(ServerApp.scala:174)
    at jupyter.scala.JupyterScalaApp.delayedEndpoint$jupyter$scala$JupyterScalaApp$1(JupyterScala.scala:93)
    at jupyter.scala.JupyterScalaApp$delayedInit$body.apply(JupyterScala.scala:13)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at caseapp.App$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(App.scala:47)
    at caseapp.App$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(App.scala:46)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at caseapp.App$class.apply(App.scala:46)
    at jupyter.scala.JupyterScalaApp.apply(JupyterScala.scala:13)
    at caseapp.AppOf.main(App.scala:121)
    at jupyter.scala.JupyterScala.main(JupyterScala.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at coursier.cli.qJ.a(Unknown Source)
    at coursier.cli.qI.j(Unknown Source)
    at coursier.cli.qO.a(Unknown Source)
    at d.g.a.c(Unknown Source)
    at b.b.d_(Unknown Source)
    at d.b.d.E.g(Unknown Source)
    at d.b.e.aU.g(Unknown Source)
    at a.c.a(Unknown Source)
    at coursier.cli.qI.b(Unknown Source)
    at coursier.cli.O.b(Unknown Source)
    at b.I.d_(Unknown Source)
    at d.E.h(Unknown Source)
    at a.aH.a(Unknown Source)
    at coursier.cli.Coursier.main(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at coursier.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:412)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ammonite.runtime.Classpath$.classpath(Classpath.scala:31)
    at ammonite.interp.Interpreter.init(Interpreter.scala:93)
    at ammonite.interp.Interpreter.processModule(Interpreter.scala:409)
    at ammonite.interp.Interpreter$$anonfun$10.apply(Interpreter.scala:151)
    at ammonite.interp.Interpreter$$anonfun$10.apply(Interpreter.scala:148)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at ammonite.interp.Interpreter.<init>(Interpreter.scala:148)
    at jupyter.scala.Interp$$anon$3.<init>(Interp.scala:41)
    at jupyter.scala.Interp.<init>(Interp.scala:41)
    at jupyter.scala.JupyterScalaApp$$anon$5.apply(JupyterScala.scala:98)
    at jupyter.scala.JupyterScalaApp$$anon$5.apply(JupyterScala.scala:97)
    at jupyter.kernel.server.Server$.launch(Server.scala:80)
    at jupyter.kernel.server.Server$.apply(Server.scala:123)
    at jupyter.kernel.server.ServerApp$$anonfun$4.apply(ServerApp.scala:171)
    at jupyter.kernel.server.ServerApp$$anonfun$4.apply(ServerApp.scala:171)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at jupyter.kernel.server.ServerApp$.apply(ServerApp.scala:171)
    ... 36 more
[I 12:35:11.027 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jupyter.kernel.server.ServerApp$.apply(ServerApp.scala:174)
    at jupyter.scala.JupyterScalaApp.delayedEndpoint$jupyter$scala$JupyterScalaApp$1(JupyterScala.scala:93)
    at jupyter.scala.JupyterScalaApp$delayedInit$body.apply(JupyterScala.scala:13)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at caseapp.App$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(App.scala:47)
    at caseapp.App$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(App.scala:46)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at caseapp.App$class.apply(App.scala:46)
    at jupyter.scala.JupyterScalaApp.apply(JupyterScala.scala:13)
    at caseapp.AppOf.main(App.scala:121)
    at jupyter.scala.JupyterScala.main(JupyterScala.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at coursier.cli.qJ.a(Unknown Source)
    at coursier.cli.qI.j(Unknown Source)
    at coursier.cli.qO.a(Unknown Source)
    at d.g.a.c(Unknown Source)
    at b.b.d_(Unknown Source)
    at d.b.d.E.g(Unknown Source)
    at d.b.e.aU.g(Unknown Source)
    at a.c.a(Unknown Source)
    at coursier.cli.qI.b(Unknown Source)
    at coursier.cli.O.b(Unknown Source)
    at b.I.d_(Unknown Source)
    at d.E.h(Unknown Source)
    at a.aH.a(Unknown Source)
    at coursier.cli.Coursier.main(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at coursier.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:412)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ammonite.runtime.Classpath$.classpath(Classpath.scala:31)
    at ammonite.interp.Interpreter.init(Interpreter.scala:93)
    at ammonite.interp.Interpreter.processModule(Interpreter.scala:409)
    at ammonite.interp.Interpreter$$anonfun$10.apply(Interpreter.scala:151)
    at ammonite.interp.Interpreter$$anonfun$10.apply(Interpreter.scala:148)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at ammonite.interp.Interpreter.<init>(Interpreter.scala:148)
    at jupyter.scala.Interp$$anon$3.<init>(Interp.scala:41)
    at jupyter.scala.Interp.<init>(Interp.scala:41)
    at jupyter.scala.JupyterScalaApp$$anon$5.apply(JupyterScala.scala:98)
    at jupyter.scala.JupyterScalaApp$$anon$5.apply(JupyterScala.scala:97)
    at jupyter.kernel.server.Server$.launch(Server.scala:80)
    at jupyter.kernel.server.Server$.apply(Server.scala:123)
    at jupyter.kernel.server.ServerApp$$anonfun$4.apply(ServerApp.scala:171)
    at jupyter.kernel.server.ServerApp$$anonfun$4.apply(ServerApp.scala:171)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at jupyter.kernel.server.ServerApp$.apply(ServerApp.scala:171)
    ... 36 more
```

And the kernel keeps restarting indefinitely.

I tried searching a solution for this everywhere but couldn't seem to find one. Even reinstalling the `jupyter-scala` kernel didn't help. Is there any other alternative to install Jupyter kernel for Scala?

I'm new to Scala. What should I do?

System Specs: MacBook, OS X El Capitan; Jupyter installation is part of Anaconda; Java version 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out what was the problem:

> JDK 8 should be used instead of JDK 9.

Setting Java 8 in `$JAVA_HOME` solved the problem by adding the following line to `~/.profile`.

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

Detail:

It is stated in the [main website](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/) that Java 8 is a requirement for running Scala. After installing through Homebrew, Scala seemed to work fine in the terminal, even with Java 9. Running Scala directly from the unpacked [binaries](https://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/2.12.5/scala-2.12.5.tgz) also worked just as well. So I never doubted the Java version to be the trouble.

As a last resort I installed Java 8 through Homebrew (making it work is [another story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487144/how-to-set-the-java-path-installed-by-homebrew/49492377#49492377)) and it turned out that that was the required solution. I presume that the latest Scala can already deal with Java 9 but the `jupyter-scala` package can only cope with Java 8.

Comment: This isn't fixing the issue on Ubuntu 18