# How to set the Java path installed by Homebrew?

Tags: java, macos, path, homebrew

Java 9 is installed in my MacBook (OS X 10.11 El Capitan). As I needed Java 8, I've installed it using Homebrew.

```
$ brew cask install java8
```

However, the Java version is still 9 in the terminal.

```
$ java -version
java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)
```

The install location of the current Java seems to be in `/System/Library/Frameworks/.../Commands`

```
$ ls -la /usr/bin/java
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Sep 23  2017 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

Homebrew seems to have installed Java 8 in

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/
```

Of course I could just prepend the above path to the `PATH` environment variable in `~/.profile`, but I wanted to know whether there is a more robust way of setting the path for the older Java version.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I use the method suggested by [Maarten Mulders](https://maarten.mulders.tk/blog/2017/02/quickly-switch-java-versions-macos.html).

I added the following to my bash profile (the file `.bash_profile` in my home directory).

```
alias j9="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 9`; java -version"
alias j8="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`; java -version"
alias j7="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`; java -version"
```

When I want to change to a Java version, I simply execute `j7` in the terminal.

Comment: Best answer ever!

Comment: I just added a java11 with this command `brew install java11` but when I run `ls -la /usr/bin/java` it points to noting `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  138880 Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/java`