# Java version confusion need to set JAVA_HOME to Java11

Tags: java, macos, azul-zulu

I'm not able to set Java11 to my JAVA_HOME env

I installed Java through home brew, how can I switch the version?
I needed to intall this java zulu to run Salesforce Data loader.

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.12+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.12+0, mixed mode)

$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    16.0.2 (x86_64) "Azul Systems, Inc." - "Zulu 16.32.15" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home

ls -la /usr/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  138880 Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/java

ls -la /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/Current
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1 Jan  1  2020 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/Current -> A
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487144/how-to-set-the-java-path-installed-by-homebrew).

Comment: I suggest using https://sdkman.io